# I have had the urge to ask this question on SO for years but I am afraid that it will get my account blocked

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

I have wanted to ask the question below on SO for years, but I am just not sure how to put it into the right words, It's a genuine question, not just a request for resources, and I have seriously been trying to find answers, but it's just not possible without expert advice.

Can I ask this question below as it is, or do I need to do more to improve it to be a acceptable question on SO?

> **Background**
>
> In world of programming, if any programmer wants to learn a
>   programming language they usually start with hello world, it served me
>   well at least to begin with Basic, C#, JavaScript and other languages.
>
> But why is it so hard to learn developing an architecture of
>   application easily, there is no hello world I could find for
>   application architectures like (SOA, DDD etc..) I have been searching
>   for not days or months but years..
>
> My search included,
>
> Reading books ("10 Real world examples in SharePoint"), searching
>   google with keywords like "Application Architecture Examples",
>   "Software archi.. complex exampales" etc...
>
> Most people say you will learn it with time (as it's hard to be an
>   architect as it takes time to get grasp on topics like OOP etc..)
>
> **Question**
>
> **Is there any hello world sort of example for application architecture styles (SOA, DDD), OR any VISUAL resources like
>   application architecture diagrams that could help me see how people do
>   the application designs from simple to middle and complex applications
>   ?**

**Edit**

First of all thanks for positive feedback.

I didn't spent years reading about architectures, I spent years (not in a continuous way, on and off -- thinking when bathing or doing a quick research now & then. **I don't know how to put this into right words.**) Searching for app architectures Visual tutorials. (I started when I was newbie dev now I am a 4 year old dev.) even though I learned lot, but still there isn't any valid VISUAL resource I could find.

**Problem**
All resources I could find discuss architecture principles BUT no one shows how they are implementing them for a specific REAL world applications

**Motive to ask this on Meta**
I might be wrong on this, but my motive was to get some positive feedback from Architects on SO to help me improve this question, so it would be in accordance to SO rules and I get my answers too.

Comment: Good thing your held off. This is at once too broad, opinion based AND asking for off-site resources. Props for asking here before asking on the main site though :)

Comment: You have access to chat.  That would be a better place for your example question.

Comment: @Patrice the number of ways it's off-topic is impressive.

Comment: _"Is there any... sort of example..."_ No matter what you do, and no matter how much effort you show, this will _always_ be a resource request and off-topic. That right there is _asking for an off-site resource._ My advice? Try writing your own "hello world" style example. If you get stuck, then search on _that_ question, or if there is no question, ask about it. You'll see much better results. (Yes, it'll be hard doing it that way. But if you're unable after several searches and books to find a resource to help, it's really the best way to learn it, in my experience.)

Comment: I find it ***extremely hard*** to believe that you've spent *years* researching different architectures, including reading books on each (as you have implied), yet you are **still** grasping for understanding.  If this truly is the case, **then absolutely no example, visual resource, or diagram we can link to will help you**.  Your question is unanswerable. Your quest, never to be completed.  I'd suggest you take up gardening.

Comment: ... which we have a site for as well, [Gardening and Landscaping](http://gardening.stackexchange.com/) but they don't do architecture...

Comment: You need to get out more...

Comment: When you learn electrical engineering, you start with wiring a light bulb to a switch. Why is there no "light bulb and switch" example for designing a smart thermostat? When you learn how to sew, you start with patching a hole in your pants. Why is there no "patching a hole" tutorial for creating a wedding dress? When you learn cooking, you start with a pancake recipe. Why is there no pancake recipe for planning a restaurant menu?

Comment: @JoshCaswell Actually, patching holes is not a "basic" task for someone who wishes to learn to sew.  Learning how to sew in a straight line is.

Comment: If we really need to parse out my analogy this finely, @cinnamon, then yes, you're right, sewing a patch was (IIRC) the _second_ thing I learned when I was taught how to sew. Firing up the compiler and putting a semicolon at the end of a line were the _first_ things I learned -- before Hello World -- when I was figuring out C.

Comment: *"but it's just not possible without expert advice"* - no its impossible without expertise. Other experts are not going to be able to just transmit expertise to you, that's your own responsibility. It comes with actually applying your knowledge and learning from a mountain of mistakes.

Comment: @Gimby you and rest of all gave excellent advise, BUT you can't make a mistake in application architecture when you work for a company who owns number of projects which is not ready (certain factors) to apply new patterns (or Tech) - off course your advise for a consultant (sort of dev) will work, but not for a developer like me who is working on same sort of architecture for 4 years, what I really want to see is how other people architect there applications, softwares so I could compare them to ours and then learn from difference (my mind is literally stuck on this way of learning by compari)

Comment: @PleaseTeach so go to conventions.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your question is too broad and is in fact a tutorial request. Those questions are off-topic here.

I don't see any way to improve your question to make it suitable on StackOverflow.

I would recommend to keep working as a programmer. With years comes experience and you will probably get to know some often used patterns. A bunch of them together yields an architecture. You need to read up to a lot of theory behind these pattern. You will eventually get to the point you want to reach when you are ready for it.

Answer (score 4):

I'd suggest finding a few architects that could be mentors to help you figure this out as this isn't a fit for SO, Programmers SE or other Q & A sites. Architecture can be quite complex though I'd imagine there could be "System Design" and "Project Management" theory that may be applicable as general areas if you wanted a thumbnail view of an answer.

There isn't a simple answer here as this would be like asking all the ways to write Literature in English having learned the letters and words of the language. It really isn't a fair question since there are more than a few factors in terms of what may work and how long would it work given that the processes are still evolving.